# Typescript function signature property with multiple type depending of running time value

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a function called `onSubmit`, inside a factory object, which creates its own methods and access properties depending of a specific running time value.

```js
const formByValue = setupFormByValue(value);
```

```js
const setupFormByValue = (value: "x" | "y") => {
  switch (value) {
    case "x":
      return xConstruct();
    default:
      return yConstruct();
  }
};
```

```js
// Different props signatures
type Values = {
  x: {
    testX: string
  };
  y: {
    testY: string
  }
};

// Possible running time values
type SubmitProps<T extends "x" | "y"> = {
  values: Values[T];
};

const xConstruct = () => {
  return {
    onSubmit: async (props: SubmitProps<"x">) => {
       /// Access props.testX
    }
  }
}

const yConstruct = () => {
  return {
    onSubmit: async (props: SubmitProps<"y">) => {
       /// Access props.testY
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use `formByValue.onSubmit({ values })`, Typescript is arguing I'm trying to use `values` with different signatures. As I have different values types("x" or "y").

Example:

[image]

Do you see how I can have both `x` and `y` with the same function signature and types and running time?

You can check what I'm trying to do here: https://codesandbox.io/s/function-signature-type-running-change-playground-rxugd2

Thank you all!

Comment: I know why you are getting that specific error, but before answering I would like to understand better the motivation of your code structure. For example, why is it important to have two onSubmit functions signatures, instead of a single signature which handles both param types like this: onSubmit: async (props: SubmitProps<"x"> | SubmitProps<"y">) => {...}? Similarly, why do you need to setup the onSubmit handlers based on "x" and "y" instead of setting them up once you know whether you have SubmitProps<"x"> or SubmitProps<"y">

Comment: Basically, because I'm going to have the same function being used my multiple possible values. Imagine that in the future, new values will come. Like, "a",  "b", "c" and etc... 

I tried to create an abstraction where I can add new possibles values and its signatures.

Comment: I don't think I understand why you have a separation between the union of the "x", "y", "z", etc values and the type of the actual values that go inside the onSubmit() function - can you not modify the Values type to be a tagged union where the tag will be "x", "y", "z", etc and then onSubmit() will handle that tagged union by dispatching to a concrete function which handles only one of the types of the union? If this sounds reasonable, I can describe it in more detail in the answer.